# weblogic 12c migration issue - No available router to destination

Tags: jsf, weblogic, weblogic12c, icefaces, weblogic11g

I have an application which is running in weblogic 10.3. I migrated the application to weblogic 12c with java version 1.8 ( earlier java version is 1.6).

when deploying the application I am getting the below exception in logs

> 2017-06-29 13:44:21,480 -  INFO (Configuration.java:1547) - Configured SessionFactory: null
>   2017-06-29 13:44:21,527 -  INFO (NamingHelper.java:26) - JNDI InitialContext properties:{java.naming.provider.url=t3s://xxxx.xxx.xxx.com:4040, java.naming.factory.initial=weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory}
>   2017-06-29 13:44:22,097 - ERROR (NamingHelper.java:33) - Could not obtain initial context
>   javax.naming.CommunicationException: t3s://xxxx.xxx.xxx.com:4040: Destination 10.xx.xx.xx, 4040 unreachable; nested exception is: 
>       java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host; No available router to destination [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: t3s://xxxx.xxx.xxx.com:4040: Destination 10.xx.xx.xx, 4040 unreachable; nested exception is: 
>       java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host; No available router to destination]
>       at weblogic.jndi.internal.ExceptionTranslator.toNamingException(ExceptionTranslator.java:40)
>       at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.toNamingException(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:808)
>       at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:365)
>       at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:319)
>       at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:288)
>       at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactory.java:117)
>       at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
>       at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
>       at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
>       at javax.naming.InitialContext.(InitialContext.java:216)
>       at org.hibernate.util.NamingHelper.getInitialContext(NamingHelper.java:28)
>       at org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.configure(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:52)
>       at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:124)
>       at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:56)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createConnectionProvider(SettingsFactory.java:414)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:62)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2073)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1298)
>       at com.xxxxx.k2.util.HibernateHelper.init(HibernateHelper.java:19)
>       at com.xxxxx.k2.servlet.StartupServlet.contextInitialized(StartupServlet.java:49)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:678)
>       at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>       at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
>       at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.executeContextListener(EventsManager.java:243)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:200)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:185)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1838)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2876)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1661)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:823)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
>       at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)
>       at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:73)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
>       at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
>       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
>       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:226)
>       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:418)
>       at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:51)
>       at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:200)
>       at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:30)
>       at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:240)
>       at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:169)
>       at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:123)
>       at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:210)
>       at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:118)
>       at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:78)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1017)
>       at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:388)
>       at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:430)
>       at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
>       at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:225)
>       at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:82)
>       at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2488)
>       at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:98)
>       at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:606)
>       at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:77)
>       at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:231)
>       at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:254)
>       at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:413)
>       at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
>       at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:225)
>       at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:82)
>       at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2488)
>       at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:98)
>       at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
>       at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1162)
>       at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1147)
>       at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
>       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
>       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: t3://xxxx.xxx.xxx.com:4040: Destination 10.xx.xx.xx, 4040 unreachable; nested exception is: 
>       java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host; No available router to destination
>       at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateInternal(RJVMFinder.java:241)
>       at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreate(RJVMFinder.java:169)
>       at weblogic.rjvm.ServerURL.findOrCreateRJVM(ServerURL.java:177)
>       at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:350)
>       ... 82 more
>   Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Destination 10.xx.xx.xx, 4040 unreachable; nested exception is: 
>       java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host; No available router to destination
>       at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.bootstrap(ConnectionManager.java:490)
>       at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.bootstrap(ConnectionManager.java:328)
>       at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMManager.findOrCreateRemoteInternal(RJVMManager.java:300)
>       at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMManager.findOrCreate(RJVMManager.java:204)
>       at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateRemoteServer(RJVMFinder.java:263)
>       at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateInternal(RJVMFinder.java:225)
>       ... 85 more

Error message when opening home page:

> 

Error 500--Internal Server Error

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.icesoft.faces.context.View.reportException(View.java:318)
    at com.icesoft.faces.context.View.servePage(View.java:200)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.SingleViewServer.service(SingleViewServer.java:84)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.common.ServerProxy.service(ServerProxy.java:43)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainSessionBoundServlet$4.service(MainSessionBoundServlet.java:187)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.BasicAdaptingServlet.service(BasicAdaptingServlet.java:51)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:55)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionDispatcher.service(SessionDispatcher.java:100)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:55)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:205)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at javax.faces.context.FacesContext.getExceptionHandler(FacesContext.java:284)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.JsfLifecycleExecutor.apply(JsfLifecycleExecutor.java:50)
    at com.icesoft.faces.context.View$2$1.respond(View.java:85)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.ServletRequestResponse.respondWith(ServletRequestResponse.java:242)
    at com.icesoft.faces.context.View$2.serve(View.java:119)
    at com.icesoft.faces.context.View.servePage(View.java:192)
    ... 29 more
```

Comment: front end exception images attached

Comment: Please post errors as text, not images

Comment: @Kukeltje added the text